What size gray conduit do i accommodate (3) 2awg wires and (1) 6awg ground wire
What size gray conduit do i use to pull (3) 2awg wires and (1) 6awg ground wire 300 feet

There are conduit fill charts that are easy to find.

By "gray conduit" are you referring to PVC?  Also, what type of wire are you using? (THHN? USE-2? XHHW? is it compact stranded?)

https://www.southwire.com/calculator-conduit

Need to know your wire type.  Need to know your conduit type (they're all gray).

Electrical conduit is gray to make it clearly different from ordinary water pipe. But there are two types - Schedule 40 and Schedule 80. Schedule 80 is thicker and is required in certain situations for physical protection of the wires. For a long run (and 300 feet is pretty long) if the conduit is buried most of the run then you can use Schedule 40 for most of it and switch to Schedule 80 where required.
There are also some differences depending on wire type. Note that cables are different from individual wires. Pulling a 4-wire cable through conduit can be a lot harder than pulling 4 individual wires, and depending on the specifics may require a larger conduit.
According to the Southwire conduit fill calculator (referenced in a comment, but that is my usual recommended site anyway), the result is 1-1/4" whether PVC Schedule 40 or Schedule 80 and whether using THHN, XHHW or RHH-USE. The results vary, but all combinations I tried worked with 1-1/4" and did not work with 1".

Just pulled 2-2-2-4 USE-2/RHH into 1.25" last week. If this is your plan be sure to use some wire lube (Ideal 31-378, 31-388, 31-358), especially at 300'. USE-2 definitely doesn't slide like Simpull  THWN!
